When I build my C# app the values in colors.xml do not appear
I'm converting my Xamarin app (for Android) to .NET 8. The app source code in Resources/values has these files:
colors.xml:
  <resources>
        <color name="colorPrimary">#DD5706</color>
        <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#1B3147</color>
        <color name="colorAccent">#8167E6</color>
       
      <color name="white">#ffffff</color>
      <color name="darkwhite">#EFFFFE</color>
      <color name="transparent">#00ffff</color>
      <color name="semitransparent">#880000</color>
      <color name="orange">#ff8800</color>
      <color name="light_orange">#e27d18</color>
      <color name="light_blue">#87CEEB</color>
      <color name="black">#000000</color>
      <color name="menuButtonColor">#ea8e44</color>
      <color name="btn_normal">#ea8e44</color>
      <color name="pressed_color">#e27d18</color>
      <color name="default_color">#f8f1e7</color>
      <color name="selected">#f8dcd3</color>
    </resources>

And in the drawable folder is background.xml:
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
  <item android:drawable="@android:color/background_light" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>      
  <item android:drawable="@color/orange" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true"/>      
  <item android:drawable="@color/light_blue" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>    
</selector>

Yet when I build the app I see a series of errors like this:
resource color/orange (aka com.xyz.MyApp:color/orange) not found.
 

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Someone suggested adding this to the csproj file:
 
